# How to efficiently navigate on a Firebase Realtime Database table? What would be an example of good documentation?

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design, documentation

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, re-frame, reagent, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project. This stack is new for me.

In addition, this project uses Firebase which is also new for me. In order to develop some features and solve some bugs, I need to go see stuff on Firebase, especially the "Data" in the Realtime Database section.

But, when I arrive there, I feel kind of lost.
[image]
1 - I need to click multiple things to find the data I am looking for. It is very manual, error-prone, lucky-based... An inefficient trial and error process

2 - executing the command "Expand all nodes" does **not** expand everything, but just some parts, so, I really need to click a lot

3 - Most of the time, I just wanna check out the last thing that I introduced on the data base. I wish there was some way to optimize the search for that.

Thus, I would like to ask:

(i) - is there some way to find just the last data added?

(ii) - is there some way to really expand everything?

(iii) - what would be the gold standard for a situation like this? Is it expected that the project will have documentation explaining this graph structure?

(iv) - if the gold standard for a situation like this is documentation, could you point a good example? Maybe something from an open-source project?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [ask] [Help]
[Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. Asking for off-site resources is explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there some way to find just the last data added?

No, you can only query it if you store a timestamp along with it.

> is there some way to really expand everything?

You can export the data as JSON and use a JSON viewer locally.

> what would be the gold standard for a situation like this?

I'm not sure why do you need to access data on a production app directly. If you need to monitor some activity then it'll be best to create an internal dashboard